# Is there a way to revalidate all paths using on-demand revalidation for ISR in Next.js?

Tags: next.js, navigation, incremental-static-regeneration

We have a Next.js site that relies heavily on ISR (incremental static regeneration) and uses webhooks to revalidate specific pages on-demand when their content has changed in our CMS.

However, we also want to keep some site-wide data in our CMS.  Particularly we want our CMS to be the source of truth for our navigation header and for a global message banner that can show special notifications on occassion.  (Ie, "We're closed today it's a special holiday")

If either of these "site-wide" things change in the CMS, we would need to revalidate every single path.  Is there a way to do this without trying to keep track of every potential path ourselves and explicitly calling revalidate on them?  It seems like the framework should help us here, but I can't find any mechanism that would revalidate everything at once.

Has anyone solved this or found good patterns for leveraging ISR with site-wide data like a navigation or global notification banner?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you can't revalidate all at the same time, but you can make an api endpoint which iterates over the pages directory, accessing its url and making a request to each page. I doubt this is good practice though.

```
async function revalidateAllPages() {
  const pagesDirectory = path.join(process.cwd(), 'pages');
  const pageFiles = await fs.readdir(pagesDirectory);

  for (const file of pageFiles) {
    if (file.endsWith('.js') && file !== 'revalidate-all.js') {
      const pagePath = path.join(pagesDirectory, file);
      const { revalidate } = await getStaticProps();

      // Trigger revalidation for each page by accessing its URL
      await fetch(`https://your-website.com/${file.replace('.js', '')}`);
    }
  }
}
```